# Understanding predict( ) in R

Tags: r, predict

I am reading through predict() in R and am confused:

There is a dataset Spam from which we have created a train data and test data using random sampling. We have used the trainSpam(training data set to train the system). We want to see how good the model is, by testing on the test dataset(testSpam).

```
predictionModel = glm(numType ~ charDollar, family = "binomial", data = trainSpam)

predictionTest = predict(predictionModel, testSpam) 
predictedSpam = rep("nonspam", dim(testSpam)[1]) 
predictedSpam[predictionModel$fitted > 0.5] = "spam" #Here is my problem
table(predictedSpam, testSpam$type)
```

In the line where we say:

```
predictedSpam[predictionModel$fitted > 0.5] = "spam"
```

How does `predictionModel$fitted` predict spams in the test data. It seems to be using predictionModel$fitted from the training data. Then we go on to compare with the spams of test data. Can someone explain?

Here is what I understood. In the line:

> predictionModel = glm(numType ~ charDollar, family = "binomial", data
>   = trainSpam)

We create a model using the trainSpam data.

In the next line:

> predictionTest = predict(predictionModel, testSpam)

We create predictionTest using the same model but the test data.

In the next line:

> predictedSpam = rep("nonspam", dim(testSpam)[1])

We created a vector with all values "nonspam"

In the next line:

> predictedSpam[predictionModel$fitted > 0.5] = "spam"

We are using the predictionModel$fitted, which has been fitted over the training data to decide which of the rows are to be classified as spam. Shouldn't we rather use something like predictionTest to identify the spams?

My idea of what it should be is:

```
> predictionModel = glm(numType ~ charDollar, family = "binomial", data = trainSpam)

> predictionTest = predict(predictionModel, testSpam,type="response")
> predictedSpam = rep("nonspam", dim(testSpam)[1])
> predictedSpam[predictionTest > 0.5] = "spam"
> table(predictedSpam, testSpam$type)
```

Comment: Shoudn't be `predictedSpam[predictionTest > 0.5] = "spam"` instead `predictedSpam[predictionModel$fitted > 0.5] = "spam"` ?

Comment: See slides by Hadley Wickham showing the application of predict(): http://stat405.had.co.nz/lectures/23-modelling.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure I follow either option just yet, as you didn't provide an example of what `trainSpam` is.  Certainly if `length(predictionModel$fitted)` is != `length(predictedSpam)`, Rcoster's note will fail.    Can you re-edit to clarify what your code and data are?

Comment: I saw this in the coursera slides and just want help understanding this.

Comment: So it looks like `charDollar` is in both test and train sets so you should not be getting predictions in `predictionTest` from the training set.

Comment: Have a look at the PDF:https://github.com/jtleek/dataanalysis/blob/master/week2/002structureOfADataAnalysis2/structureOfADataAnalysis2.pdf

Comment: Questions to SO should be (mostly) self-contained. SO is a coding site, not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `type="response"` in the `predict` call, since the default will otherwise be the linear predictor.

```
?predict.glm    # different than ?predict
```

(This is, of course, if I am correctly intuiting your unstated goal to be finding cases in your test set with probabilities greater than 0.5. Furthermore, if you are really getting predictions based on training data, it means your test dataframe was malformed, and that you need to edit your question to contain output from both `str(trainSpam)` and `str(testSpam)` so we can show you how to properly create a `data` argument for `predict`.)

After update: So it looks like `charDollar` is in both test and train sets, so you should not be getting predictions in `predictionTest` from the training set. You should get predicted > 50% Spam cases with:
     testSpam[ predict(fit, data=testSpam, type="response) > .5 ]

I'm not sure what code was used to create `predictionTest` and wonder if you meant to type `predictedSpam`. This is what I thought would succeed:

```
predictedSpam = predict(predictionModel, testSpam) 
spam <- predictedSpam[ predictedSpam$fitted > 0.5 ]
```

Comment: Pdf link where this example is stated:https://github.com/jtleek/dataanalysis/blob/master/week2/002structureOfADataAnalysis2/structureOfADataAnalysis2.pdf